# R dplyr filter not working right with mildly complex filter

Tags: r, dplyr

`dplyr` filter not working when I have a list subsetting in the check Value.
Samething works when I assign to to variable. See code below

```
df1<-data.frame(x=1:26, y=letters, stringsAsFactors = F)
templist<-list(alpha=df1)
res<-df1 %>% filter(y %in% templist$alpha$y)
nrow(res)
[1] 0
tempLetters <- templist$alpha$y
res<-df1 %>% filter(y %in% tempLetters)
nrow(res)
[1] 26
```

I thought this used to work earlier. Please help. Note that the column names are same in both (y) by design.

I have updated `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `pipeR` to the latest versions on cran just now (4 jan, 2017)

Comment: I think it may be a bug or the name clash, try with `filter(df1, y %in% templist$alpha[[2]])` or even `filter(df1, y %in% templist$alpha[["y"]])`

Comment: Are you sure `filter()` is the function you want? `Select()` may be more useful e.g  `select(df1$alpha,y)` or for the list `select(templist$alpha,y)`

Comment: Andrew I just gave a simple example to highlight the issue. @akrun you are correct. The issue happens with name clashes!

Comment: Also it only fails when there is a third level of indirection (list$dataframe$columnname) ex: df1<-data.frame(x=1:26, y=letters, stringsAsFactors = F)
df2<-data.frame(a=1:10, y=letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = F)
res<-df1 %>% filter(y %in% df2$y)
nrow(res) works just fine

Answer (score 1):

@hadleywickham has confirmed that this is a known bug fixed in dev

Pls see his response on twitter at:
https://twitter.com/gunapemmaraju/status/816639470166544384